# How can I make a donation app for google play to attach to the free version?

Tags: java, android, apk, donations

I have a app on the Google Play and I want to add a donation app. I could just put the same game on the market that's modified to say donation version but They wont have there saves from the free version. Is there a way for me to just create a .apk that apon run it will change say a boolean donated = true in the free version and then hide itself from app list. Or is there a way more easy way to do this?

Comment: create a new apk with the donation feature and update the apk in google play store.

Answer (score 1):

You can share data between applications i.e using sd card, named preferences, content providers.
Other way to solve your problem is using in-app payments. The adventage is, that you do not need to mantain 2 code branches for free/paid apps.
If we are talking about payments - take a look at Google Play's policy - in general they do not allow using other (cheaper) "payment processors".

Comment: If both the free version and the donation version had the same package name. would that work? It would essentially be a update for the free version because of the version in the manifest.

Comment: I'm not writing about free and donation versions. I'm about introducing in-app payments into your free application. Every app published into GP must have unique package name (in manifest).

Comment: Do you know where I can get the api or/and a example for the in app payments?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html I'm not sure that free app can be turned into in-app payments in GP - you have to checki it out.